# jQuery Visualize Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a tutorial that is well written that can help me with the jQuery visualize plugin. Its used for having data that will transform into a graph of some sort whether it be bar, pie, line which ever. But the data I want used is going to come from my server in which I use php and that data will be made up of visits to my main page and visits to my login page for my CMS with code igniter.

Any ideas on any?

Comment: This should be useful, upvoting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a tutorial... however The [Filament Group](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/) has written a (IMO) nice plugin for JQuery. They generally have clear code you can read and pull out some ideas.. it's a start!

Other examples include:

- [JSVis](http://code.google.com/p/jsviz/)
- [PreFuse](http://prefuse.org/)
- [JPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)

[Or you can look here](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/12/70-tools-for-visualizing-your-data-css-flash-jquery-php.html)

Comment: It looks nice but I'm not seeing how I can get php data used here.

Comment: Pass it back as JSON or as a HTML Table and apply the JQuery plugin to the table.

Comment: Do you know of any other links I could take a look at. I'm trying to do a search and not getting very far?

Comment: I'm looking for something I can use for a server side to get my data of how many hits to two different urls.

Comment: ohh ok, i thought you already had that. you are then in fact looking for two things. ummm, this looks ok. http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Create-Php-Based-Hit-Counter_t1013.html just modify it to store data from two sites instead of one.

Comment: Is there a way to get the information from google analytics or what not?